# org-export-run-in-background: How to troubleshoot?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to use emacs-24 with org-mode such that org-export-run-in-background is enabled. However, I get obscure messages in *Org Processes:

> Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server. There is an
>   existing Emacs server, named "server". To start the server in this
>   Emacs process, stop the existing server or call `M-x
>   server-force-delete' to forcibly disconnect it. OVERVIEW Loading
>   vc-git... Exporting... my-java-mode-hook my-java-mode-hook Symbol's
>   function definition is void: nil

I'd really like to figure out how to get a stack trace or some other way to debug this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the first time I had tried [exporting in the background](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-export-dispatcher.html) and it worked for me. Since my org-export-run-in-background variable is nil, I had to test it via 'C-u C-u C-c C-e'.

I have seen your error before when my previous Emacs session was shutdown improperly and the next session thought there was already a server running. I would try following the recommendation of calling 'M-x server-force-delete' and then ensure your server is running via 'M-x server-start'. After that, re-try your export.

If you are still having trouble, check on which processes are still out there running. I use a couple of methods: 1. Emacs method of running 'M-x list-processes' or a bash shell command of "pstree -lp $(pgrep emacs)".